# give a hint when press prefix key in tmux

Tags: tmux

When I press the prefix-key <kbd>Ctrl-b</kbd> tmux doesn't give me a hint that it has been pressed.

Sometimes I can not remember whether I have already pressed it or not.

Can I set up a hint like highlight/change color or show some special symbol in the status bar to show me when I have pressed the prefix-key?

Comment: There is nothing like this built into *tmux*, but it [came up](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.tmux.user/3121) on the mailing list recently. Nothing has been incorporated into the main source yet though.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The development version of *tmux* has support for this, so the next release (1.8?) should also support it.

There have been two changes that can be combined to indicate in your status line whether a prefix key has been pressed:

- You can include the extended “format” replacements in the values of the “status” options. These replacements were first available in *tmux* 1.6, but they were not previously usable in the status options.
- The `client_prefix` format replacement was added.

You could add a (conditional) highlighted `<Prefix>` string before the default `status-right` like this:

```
set -g status-right ' #{?client_prefix,#[reverse]<Prefix>#[noreverse] ,}"#{=21:pane_title}" %H:%M %d-%b-%y'
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the `"#22T"`? In my computer it literally shows this code in the tmux's status bar and removing it seems harmless.

Comment: `#T` is the short version of `#{pane_title}`. The intervening number used to limit the length of the substituted value (so `#22T` would only show the first 22 characters of `pane_title` if it was too long). It was part of the (old) default value of `status-right`. The newer `#{var_name}` substitution syntax uses a different length-limiting syntax: `#{=NN:var_name}`. At some point support for the old length-limiting syntax must have been dropped. In modern *tmux* the default `status-right` uses `#{=21:pane_title}`. I’ll update the answer.

Comment: Also, here is how you can inspect the default value of a setting: `tmux -L none -f /dev/null start-server\; show-options -g status-right` (where `none` is a currently unused *tmux* server socket name).

Comment: I use the following for displaying it on the left side of the status bar (in case anyone else was wondering): `set -g status-left '#{?client_prefix,#[reverse]<Prefix>#[noreverse] ,}[#S] '`

Comment: This was really helpful.

Answer (score 7):

I created plugin for this. It indicates copy mode as well, is easily customizable and has good out-of-the-box experience.

https://github.com/dominikduda/tmux_mode_indicator

As readme says:

> Plugin indicating normal/insert/prefix/copy modes.

It adds a new keyword, #{tmux_mode_indicator} to use in the string that defines your tmux status bar. Like this:

```
set -g status-right "#{tmux_mode_indicator}"
```

Answer (score 6):

There's also a Tmux plugin called [tmux-prefix-highlight](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-prefix-highlight) that does this.
It adds a new keyword, `#{prefix_highlight}` to use in the string that defines your tmux status bar, like so:

```
set -g status-right '#{prefix_highlight} | %a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```